# What keystrokes does 'C-p' mean in 'info' utility?

Tags: info

Using <kbd>H</kbd> within `info` there are a series of options like

```
'C-n' ('next-line')
<DOWN> (an arrow key)
     Move the cursor down to the next line.

'C-p' ('prev-line')
<UP> (an arrow key)
     Move the cursor up to the previous line.
```

But I am not sure how to invoke them with keystrokes. I tried Shift+C then the next character (i.e Shift+C+p) but that did not work. Also tried C followed quickly by p . . .

Basic question - but have not yet found much direction.

Comment: @αғsнιη Command (⌘) is separate from Control, though. (But don't know about how Emacs deals with them.) My Chrome shows the hotkey for Full Screen as ^⌘F, so Ctrl-Cmd-F.

Answer (score 3):

`C-c` is Ctrl-C. Or Ctrl+C. Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or `^C`. A dear child has many names. See e.g. the [list of notations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#Notation).

Similarly, `M-c` is Meta+c. Current systems don't have [a key called that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key), usually, so Alt-c usually works as a substitute. Here, there might be a difference between an uppercase and a lowercase letter.

See also: [What does the ^ character mean in sequences like ^X^I?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/629616/170373)

Comment: Maybe add a few words on `SPC` (space), `RET` (enter) and `S` (shift)?